# Migrate Telerik Test Studio Scripts to Robot Framework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework, telerik-test-studio

Our current test automation is in Telerik Test Studio. But, the customer want to migrate existing test automation to Robot Framework or Selenium ?

1. Is there any tool/utility/script which is readily available to convert existing Telerik Test Studio scripts to Robot Framework or Selenium?
2. Are there any steps to migrate this script.

Please share your thoughts.